# Postgres SQL update one table column based on calculation of the other table's field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables as following, I want to update date_table's total field with corresponding time_table's sum(end - start) calculation result.

```
date_table
id  name    date        total
1   xx      2016-02-01
2   yy      2016-02-02

time_table
id  date_id start                   end
1   1       2016-02-01 08:00:00     2016-02-01 11:00:00 
2   1       2016-02-01 14:00:00     2016-02-01 20:00:00 
3   2       2016-02-02 08:00:00     2016-02-02 11:00:00 
4   2       2016-02-02 14:00:00     2016-02-02 20:00:00
```

So, the result will be for date_table first record total will be:

```
(2016-02-01 11:00:00 - 2016-02-01 08:00:00) + (2016-02-01 20:00:00 - 2016-02-01 14:00:00)
```

Two table joined with `date_id`

Is that something like?

```
Update date_table
SET date_table.total = 
(
  SELECT 
    sum(time_table.end - time_table.start) 
  FROM time_table 
  WHERE 
    date_table.id = time_table.date_id
)
```

Not quite sure how Postgres subtract datetime?

Comment: "*Not quite sure how Postgres subtract datetime*" - see the manual, it's all explained there. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that data type of `total` field in `date_table` is `integer` and your expected output is

```
id name date       total 
-- ---- ---------- ----- 
1  xx   2016-02-01 9     
2  yy   2016-02-02 9
```

so,

```
select dteend-dtestart col
from time_table;
```

will produce output as `interval` data type

i.e

```
col 
interval     
-------- 
03:00:00 
06:00:00 
03:00:00 
06:00:00
```

you cannot perform aggregate function on interval directly.Following method can be used to get the interval in integer data type.

```
select date_id, sum(EXTRACT(epoch FROM dteend-dtestart)/3600)::int
from time_table
group by date_id;
```

output:

```
date_id sum 
------- --- 
1       9   
2       9
```

and the update should be like following.

```
UPDATE date_table
SET total = t.sum
FROM (
    SELECT date_id
        ,sum(EXTRACT(epoch FROM dteend - dtestart) / 3600)::INT
    FROM time_table
    GROUP BY date_id
    ) t
WHERE date_table.id = t.date_id;
```